# Can you advertise against another product using domain names?

Tags: trademark, advertisements, domain-name, online

Suppose your competitor is about to release a product. Can you technically build a website with a domain name that includes their product name, such as

```
www.get-productname.com
www.better-than-productname.com
```

Which redirects users to your own product website?

The first option is straight up misleading and mean. The second option seems more reasonable. Is this kind of tactic illegal?

Of course those names wouldn't be able to top `www.productname.com`, but with the right marketing strategies I suppose they could at least come second or third, which would make them useful anyway.

Comment: With sufficiently competitive SEO, they could easily come up first.

Comment: @forest yes, but I reckon you can still take advantage of the second and third spots. Things like `www.productname-free.com` or `www.productname-pro.com` could easily catch people's attention, etc.

Comment: Doubt you would gain.  I sure would not buy from you after I realize I was duped.

Comment: @paparazzo You realize that a large percentage of companies make their profit exclusively from duping people, right? Consumers are, as a generalization, completely clueless and look to advertisers to teach them about the world.

Comment: @forest  What ever.   I typically figure it out before I am duped and for sure I don't come back.

Comment: @paparazzo You are a minority. :)

Comment: @forest Soo don't agree but comments are not for debate.